# I can get posts in all categories. But I want to get the custom post type I created

Tags: terms, categories

i created custom post type ('Ürünler') with some plugin. And I want to pull all posts from here with category titles. My code doesn't see the custom post type. 
I'll be happy if you can help me.

```
$argss = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);

$categories=get_categories($argss);

foreach($categories as $category) {


    $args=array(
        'showposts' => -1,
        'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
    if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <?php
        } // foreach($posts
    } // if ($posts
} // foreach($categories`
```

Answer (score 0):

Has your custom post type created with the categories? if yes just add  'post_type'=> 'your-custom-post-type' in the args. So for you it will be as below:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type'=> 'Ürünler'
    'showposts' => -1,
    'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
```